# Webpack: Style tag per required css file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to have one  tag per required .css file.

I want it like that because I want to connect chrome dev-tools workspace feature to my src folder, so I could edit my css files directly from the browser.

Here's my research on loaders:

1. style-loader only loads into style tags
2. style-loader/url + file-loader doesn't work (I tried the README example)
3. extract-text-webpack-plugin seems to only generate ONE bundle per ALL css files with default configuration.
4. The [Modify Files](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#modify-filename) section in extract-text-webpack-plugin suggests that with *multiple entry points*, it's possible to generate multiple bundles, so I thought that it might be possible to abuse this feature to get the behaviour I want.

This is of course for development and I don't intend on serving my css this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: 'css-loader'
      })
    }
  ]
},
plugins: [ 
  new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'path/to/your/index.html',
  })
],
resolve: {
  extensions: [ '.js', '.css' ]
}
```

Then in your js files, do `import path/to/your/stylesheet.css`; for each stylesheet you want webpack to extract.

**Note:** you need to install `html-webpack-plugin` and add it like above so that webpack can insert references to your stylesheets. Click [HERE](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to learn more about the options for HtmlWebpackPlugin

Comment: I get an error from within Extract Text Plugin. Have you tried this?